# Jinja - email template, date time formatting with a variable

Tags: python, email, jinja2

This is driving me crazy, feels like it should be easier.

Using Jinja code for a HTML email, in a drag and drop editor - so no access to the `<head>`!

I have a date I’ve set as a variable the date format is YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

I want to change the format using datetimeformat function, it works fine as `{{ today()|datetimeformat("%y-%m-%d") }}` - but I'll be buggered if I can exchange `today()` with my variable.

```
{% set bonusBeforeDate = linkedData.accessCodes[userAttribute['ReferralSource']]['promotion']['rules']['member_joined_date']['before'] %}
```

And then

```
{{ bonusBeforeDate|datetimeformat("%y-%m-%d") }}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, someone very kind has helped me out with this one, so I'll share it here in the hope it saves anyone else the headache later.

The reason it is not working is because datetimeformat requires datetime object, while yours is a string. The today() function returns datetime object, so it works directly. You will have to perform some transformations to get this working. The following sequence needs to be followed:

1. Convert your string to another suitable string to represent datetime object. Not all date looking strings can be converted to datetime object, they need to follow a specific format.
2. Now convert the new string to a datetime object (strtotime)
3. Apply any datetime formatting to the date time object (datetimeformat)

In practical terms with your example:

Step 1:

```
{% set myDate='2020-12-31 12:59:00' %}
{% set myDateFormatted = myDate|split(' ',2) %}
{% set myDateFinalFormat = myDateFormatted[0]+'T'+myDateFormatted[1]+'Z' %}
```

The value of myDateFinalFormat at this point should be 2020-12-31T12:59:00Z which is the exact string format we are interested in.

Steps 2 and 3:

```
{{ myDateFinalFormat|strtotime("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX")|datetimeformat("%y-%m-%d") }}
```

This will output: 20-12-31